# Cassandra Entity annotation doesn't map column correct

Tags: cassandra, annotations, entity

I have a Cassandra table "test_data_table" with columns of:
id, name, start_time, is_deleted
And id is the partition key.
I'm trying to use the bellow code to build map select statemen

```
@Entity
@CqlName("test_data_table")
data class RtawData(
  @PartitionKey var id: String? = null,
  @ClusteringColumn var name: String? = null,
  var start_time: Long? = null,
  var is_deleted: Boolean? = null
)
```

But during compile time I got Invalid CQL form [_deleted] needs double quotes.

Does Cassandra's @Enitty annotation not match columns starting with "is_"?

Comment: add explicit `CqlName` to that variable